# Android Studio: Can not find Run test choice

Tags: android, android-studio, unit-testing, testing, junit

When I try to run the unit test in a class, I can not find a Run choice
[image]

But I can see it on my teammate laptop in the same project and when clicking on the arrow beside the function and the class name it displays "Nothing here"
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps you can try to avoid reinstalling android studio, with examples from a project having working instrumented tests.
In general, if you also have a pc where the tests works, I advise you to compare all the following configurations between the two environments.
Also try to start the tests with a [preview version of Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview).

#### Enable test plugins

Go to `Android Studio -> Preferences... -> Plugins` and check if the test plugins are enabled (i.e. JUnit)

[image]

#### Update Gradle version

Go to `File > Project Structure... > Project` and update to the latest Gradle version.

#### Update Kotlin and Gradle plugin versions

Check if you're using the latest versions in your `build.gradle` (project level)

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31"
```

#### Update your test dependencies

In your `build.gradle` (module level)

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
    ...
```

#### Remove JUnit group exclusion

In the same file, if present, remove the following exclusion

```
exclude group: "org.junit.platform" //remove this line
```